# Permanently attaching Image file to Feature Class in 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, image, file-geodatabase

I need to forward on a File Geodatabase, and I am using the attachment manager to attach the file images associated with the different features in my Feature class.

If I forward on this FGD, will the images be permanently there?  I have not been able to find anything about whether it is permanent, or I would need to send the source files along, and the attachments would have to be redirected on the end of the recipient?

If not is there another way to permanently attach an image file to a Feature class in a File Geodatabse?  These photos are not geotagged, nor do they have a time stamp on them so neither of the photo tools would work on them.  There is no possibility that this can be in SDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this ESRI link [using attachments](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/21/using-attachments-to-manage-associated-feature-content/)

It states "since attachments are stored inside the geodatabase, I can share a geodatabase or make a layer or map package and all the attached files are included with the data automatically."

Comment: Thank you, this is a resource I don't usually use.

Comment: No prob and if you feel one of these answered your question you can select it as the answer so the question will be shown as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - attached image files are stored inside your file geodatabase when you create attachments there.  This is an excellent way to distribute them.